# How to set xmlns attribute of XNode object

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am creating an XML XNode object which I can send in HttpClient request for API. I want to use the class to create XML and then pass it to HttpClient.

First I created the class with the exact same name as nodes in XML. So the fields name I used was in camel case but now I want to use the pascal case.

So with the camel case, it was working but now since I needed XML in the camel case, the solution I found was to first serialize it into JSON with camel case and then deserialize JSON into XML XNode object. But then another issue arise was that the attribute xmlns attribute in the root element

Below is the code to serialize to JSON and Deserialize to XNode object

```
var resolver = new DefaultContractResolver { NamingStrategy = new CamelCaseNamingStrategy() };
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings { ContractResolver = resolver };
//serialize class to json
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(creditBureau2, settings);
//desrialize to XNode object
XNode xml2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeXNode(json, ToCamelCasing(nameof(CreditBureau)));
```

Now to set the namespace of the root element tried the below code

```
xml2.Document.Root.SetAttributeValue("xmlns", "http://www.example.com/namespace");
```

But the issue is when I checked the value of XNode object(xml2) after executing above it changes to some other format than it was before. and while sending xml2.ToString(); it throws exception. The screenshot I have attached please look into that.

[Before calling SetAttributeValue function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p13PI.png)

[After calling SetAttributeValue function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T2HP3.png)

[Exception Thrown in .ToString function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IpGcg.png)

Comment: Why don't you use XmlRootAttribute and XmlElementAttribute to annotate your class and properties so the XML gets serialized as you wish instead of going true this wasteful extra serialization steps?

Comment: Yes you are right I also thought about that also but then XML is too long and to convert each field to camel case. I will need to write a camel case for each field above each field in the class. That would be a lot of time-consuming and I personally think that it is not an ideal solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

xmlns is a reserved keyword that's why it was causing the issue. You can add the namespace to each element of xml.

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml2.ToString());
XNamespace xs = "http://www.example.com/namespace";
foreach (var elemeent in doc.Descendants())
{
    elemeent.Name = xs + elemeent.Name.LocalName;
}
```